# Is there a way to make an automatic slideshow using imageswitchers and galleries?

Tags: java, android, slideshow, imageswitcher

I'm having trouble thinking about how to make an automatic slideshow using ImageSwitchers and Gallery. The only thing I understand is the animation between transitioning pictures when you select them from gallery, like the way they fade or move from left to right.

**EDIT**

My purpose is trying to make a slideshow the same way when you create gallery and select each pictures then use imageswitcher to display the selected picture on the bottom layout. Just this time, instead actually clicking, I want the pictures to move automatically (next one after the last one), like on Powerpoints and with a timer obviously.

Here's the whole class:
package project.CaseStudy;

```
public class Slideshow extends Activity implements ViewFactory {
    //---the images to display---
    Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
            R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7
    };

    TextView legend;
    TextView imageID;

    CheckBox repeat;
    CheckBox image;
    CheckBox text;

    public int picture;
    public int pictureCurrentlySelected;

    private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slideshow);

        legend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.legend);
        imageID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imagenum);

        repeat = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.repeat);
        image = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.number);
        text = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.text);

        //text.setEnabled(true);
        //image.setEnabled(true);
        //repeat.setEnabled(true);


        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher1);
        imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);


        imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));


        /*imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
        imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right));

        */
        pictureCurrentlySelected = -1;
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View v, int position, long id)
            {
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
                picture = position;
                pictureCurrentlySelected = picture;
                check();
            }
        });
    }

    public View makeView()
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new
                ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return imageView;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private int itemBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            context = c;

            //---setting the style---
            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }

        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount()
        {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }

        //---returns the item---
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item---
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);

            return imageView;
        }
    }

    public void onCheckBoxClickListener(View v)
    {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.repeat:
            /*if(checked)
            {
                return;
            }*/
            break;

        case R.id.text:
            if(!checked)
                legend.setText("");
            else
            {
                if(pictureCurrentlySelected == -1)
                {
                    legend.setText("");
                }
                else
                    check();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.number:
            if(!checked)
                imageID.setText("");
            else
            {
                if(pictureCurrentlySelected == -1)
                {
                    legend.setText("");
                }
                else
                    check();
            }

            break;

        }
    }

    private void check()
    {
        if(text.isChecked())
        {
            if(picture == 0)
                legend.setText("This is San Fransisco's Bridge. A beautiful Sight!");
            else if(picture == 1)
                legend.setText("This is the train used to pick up the bitches around town.");
            else if(picture == 2)
                legend.setText("The outstanding lake of San Fransisco");
            else if(picture == 3)
                legend.setText("A beautiful view of the city!");
            else if(picture == 4)
                legend.setText("Beauty at its limit.");
            else if(picture == 5)
                legend.setText("Town at sunset.");
            else
                legend.setText("Bridge during within a beautiful sight.");

        }
        /*else
            legend.setText("");*/

        if(image.isChecked())
        {
            if(picture == 0)
                imageID.setText("Image number 1");
            else if(picture == 1)
                imageID.setText("Image number 2");
            else if(picture == 2)
                imageID.setText("Image number 3");
            else if(picture == 3)
                imageID.setText("Image number 4");
            else if(picture == 4)
                imageID.setText("Image number 5");
            else if(picture == 5)
                imageID.setText("Image number 6");
            else
                imageID.setText("Image number 7");

        }
        //else
            //legend.setText("");

        if(repeat.isChecked())
        {
        }
        //else;

    }

}
```

Ignore the last two methods if it's too complicated to understand Im just sketching my program and will eventually fix the redundancy later.

Here's the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Images of San Francisco" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/repeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCheckBoxClickListener"
            android:text="Repeat" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCheckBoxClickListener"
            android:text="Image ID" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCheckBoxClickListener"
            android:text="Text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50" >

        <ImageSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/switcher1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ImageSwitcher>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Image number: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imagenum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/legend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "Is there a way to..." is a *terrible* question title. Can you please explain in more detail what your question actually is? You've shown two chunks of code with little explanation of the problem.

Comment: There you go. My point is I can't think of anyway to make an automated slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but the best (read: easiest) way I know of to create a **small** slideshow is to simply put your imageViews and/or textViews into a frame layout. Then in your code, you would use a switch statement that sets the visibility of each image.

eg. case 0:

image1.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);

image2.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);

Etc....

Comment: Man I edited my question, I hope you understand. Your code is not what I'm looking for.